# pointing markers on Google map @change

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, geolocation

I have included `google map` for the project that I'm working with. I have few checkboxes which are dynamic and when click on a checkbox according to that those locations will be displayed on `google map`. As **follows**: [image: here] The thing is it is not refreshing and remove the previous markers when I check or uncheck those checkboxes again and again.

**`Vue Component`**:

```
<div v-for="vnos in vehicle_nos">
     <input class="" type="checkbox" name="vehicle_num" :value="vnos.name" v-model="vehicle_nums" @change="getVehicleNumbers(vehicle_nums)">
     <label for="vehicle_num">{{vnos.name}}</label><br>
</div>
```

**functions** I trigger:

```
getVehicleNumbers(vehicle_num){
          this.allSelectedVehicles = vehicle_num;

          axios.post('gps/get-gps-location/'+this.allSelectedVehicles)
            .then(response => {
              for (let i = 0; i < response.data.data.length; i++) {
                this.all_data = JSON.parse(response.data.data[i]);
                this.longtitudes = this.all_data.item.pos.x;
                this.latitudes = this.all_data.item.pos.y;

                let longlatitude = this.latitudes+','+this.longtitudes;
                this.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
                this.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
                //here I pass those coordinates to geocodeLatLng() function
                this.geocodeLatLng(this.geocoder, this.map, this.infowindow, longlatitude); 
              }
            }).catch(Erors => {
              console.log('errors');
          });
        },
        geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow, longlatitude = null) {

          var input = longlatitude;
          var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
          var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]), lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1])};
              //latlng looks like '6.916333,79.861018' this
          geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
            if (status === 'OK') {
              if (results[0]) {
                map.setZoom(11);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: latlng,
                  map: map,
                });
                infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);

              } else {
                // alert('No results found');
              }
            } else {
              // alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
            }
          });
        },
```

In my **`controller`** I pass the data as an array to the response in `axios.post('gps/get-gps-location/'+this.allSelectedVehicles)` this one.

Then I loop all those and set markers one by one. But what I need is to remove all markers from the `google map` and display the upcoming response data. It's not removing and shows the upcoming markers as well as existing markers also. So there are few markers on same point.

I tried most of the given examples and links on stackoverfow also but couldn't able to find a better solution. Your help is appreciated a lot.

Comment: Where are you removing your existing markers? Can you please post your full code? Check out this example for guidance https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove

Comment: @evan I've gone through that my friend. thank you for the information.

Comment: Sure thing! So I understand that you've resolved it now then? Or do you still need assistance? (if so please post all your code)

Comment: @evan Thanks a lot. I've resolved it brother

Comment: Glad to hear! :) Consider posting and accepting your own answer for the community's sake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally changed the previous code and can be used it as **follows**

```
getVehicleNumbers(vehicle_num){
    this.loading = false;

    if (vehicle_num.length == 0) {
         this.allSelectedVehicles = 0;
    } else {
         this.allSelectedVehicles = vehicle_num;
    }

    axios.post('gps/get-gps-location/'+this.allSelectedVehicles)
    .then(response => {

        this.deleteMarkers();
        for (let i = 0; i < response.data.data.length; i++) {
            this.all_data = JSON.parse(response.data.data[i]);
            this.longtitudes = this.all_data.item.pos.x;
            this.latitudes = this.all_data.item.pos.y;

            let longlatitude = {lat: this.latitudes, lng: this.longtitudes};

            this.addMarker(longlatitude);

            this.loading = true;
        }
    }).catch(Erors => {
        this.loading = true;
    });
},
addMarker(location) {

    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: this.map,
    });
    this.markersArray.push(marker);

},
setMapOnAll(map) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.markersArray.length; i++) {
        this.markersArray[i].setMap(map);
    }
},
clearMarkers() {
    this.setMapOnAll(null);
},
deleteMarkers() {
    this.clearMarkers();
    this.markersArray = [];
},
```

Once check the `checkbox` then it'll trigger `getVehicleNumbers` function. and through that the markers will be shown in the map. And if the checkbox is unchecked again the function will trigger and reset the map. then it'll show the new markers only.